# How to change file type settings in Ubuntu Beaver?

Tags: ubuntu, files, gnome, nautilus, file-types

I noticed that when I looked at my documents folder, there was an XAPK file there. I knew it was there, but Nautilus detected it as a `zip` file. I was able to change filetype settings before on my RPi, but that ran `debian buster beta`, not Ubuntu. How do I change this?

Note: My OS is Ubuntu Beaver RTM (`16.4`).

Comment: The name of a file, even allowing for any dots in the name is not wholly used to  determine the type of file; this as you would expect. Try running `mimetype yourfilename`. If it is a mimetype that `zip` recognises, then Nautilus will open it using the zip program.